# Is there a tool for exploring/testing COM objects?

Tags: windows, com, oleview

I'm trying to automate a process by using a COM object from Python (win32com), but I'm not getting the expected results... Is there a tool to explore/test COM objects without having to write a specific program? I mean, is there something that allows e.g. to instantiate a COM object and call its methods?

(Basically I'm trying to find out if my unexpected results are win32com's fault, and I'd like to avoid installing Visual Studio to write a C# app)

Answer (score 31):

I actually wrote a replacement for the SDK tool OleView (afaik it doesn't support calling methods only enumerating) unimaginatively called OleViewDotNet. You can get the source code [here](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet) or releases [here](https://github.com/tyranid/oleviewdotnet/releases).

What it does do is expose IDispatch methods (and some native interfaces) via a GUI so you can call them and it also provides an IronPython script window. You'd need to find your COM object by looking under "Registry -> CLSID By Name", find the entry (the filter can be used to select by name part) right click and select "Create Instance" that should show up a window similar to:

[image: object information]

then select the "Operations" menu at the bottom and choose "Open Dispatch" to get the method/property window.

[image]

There's a lot more you can do with this but that's a simple overview.

Answer (score 16):

If you download the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) via the WebSetup you should be able to choose to just download the SDK tools. They include a program called Ole/COM Viewer (oleview.exe) that can be used to browse all registered COM objects, and for objects that support Ole Automation, open them and invoke methods.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out if I'm using it correctly.. I've found the object I need, I click on "Create instance" and it gets selected (bold text).. What should I do now? There are a few interfaces available, but when I double-click on any of them I get "IDataObject interface viewer only supports IID_IDataObject"

Comment: Likely the package is missing iviewers.dll, which oleview.exe requires in the same directory.  See: http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/ComRef.htm

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Anyway the iviewers.dll is there, and if I move it elsewhere OLEviewer complains, so I'm guessing it's using it.. Anyway maybe I'm using it in a wrong way, what's the procedure to call a method using OLEviewer? I can't figure it out :/

Comment: The problem is I suspect, that COM is a binary contract, so theres no general way to call into random interfaces. Well there is - it relies on the type information present when building 'dual' interfaces

Comment: @Joril all you have to do is register iviewers.dll, think you need to run both versions of Regsvr32 (if you want 64 bit support too)

Answer (score 12):

I am exploring COM objects in PowerShell. Found this great [recipe](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/27/pstip-get-a-list-of-all-com-objects-available/), provided by Jaap Brasser, which is easy to run and answered my question.

> **Get a list of all Com objects available**   Posted by Jaap Brasser on June 27, 2013
>
> Note: This tip requires PowerShell 2.0 or above.
>
> Recently a question was posted on the PowerShell.com forums: How to
>   get a full list of available ComObjects? This tip will show how fetch
>   all of them from the registry.
>
> Here is the code that we can use to generate this list:
>
> ```
> Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Classes -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {
>    $_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$' -and (Test-Path -Path "$($_.PSPath)\CLSID")
> } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName
> ```
>
> The first Cmdlet reads out a complete list of values from
>   HKLM:\Software\Classes and then verifies if the following two
>   conditions are true:
>
> - Does the object match the naming convention for a ComObject?
> - Does the registry key have a CLSID folder? Every registered ComObject should have a CLSID as a unique identifier. An example of
>     the output generated by this command is as follows:
>
>   AccClientDocMgr.AccClientDocMgr
>     AccDictionary.AccDictionary
>     Access.ACCDAExtension
>     Access.ACCDCFile
>     Access.ACCDEFile
>     Access.ACCDTFile
>     Access.ACCFTFile
>     Access.ADEFile
>
> To make the process of discovering ComObject easier the following
>   function can be used.
>
> ```
> function Get-ComObject {
>
>     param(
>         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
>         ParameterSetName='FilterByName')]
>         [string]$Filter,
>
>         [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
>         ParameterSetName='ListAllComObjects')]
>         [switch]$ListAll
>     )
>
>     $ListofObjects = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\Software\Classes -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {
>         $_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$' -and (Test-Path -Path "$($_.PSPath)\CLSID")
>     } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PSChildName
>
>     if ($Filter) {
>         $ListofObjects | Where-Object {$_ -like $Filter}
>     } else {
>         $ListofObjects
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This function is available in the TechNet Script Gallery:
>
> http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-ComObject-Function-to-50a92047

Comment: Apparently this doesn't include COM visible .net  methods.

Comment: The function was removed from the TechNet Script Gallery for some reason?!