# Viewing All Properties of a COM object for VB.NET Project in Visual Studio 2010 debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a VB.NET project, and I'm looking to set a watch on a COM object in Visual Studio 2010, but I cannot get anything useful if I simply set the watch on object FooBar. When I expand the menu, all I get is the property:

```
 System.__ComObject
```

I'm looking for something a little more detailed than that, because I know that FooBar has properties like FooBar.Version, FooBar.CurrentItem, etc., but I can only set watches on properties that I explicitly know. Is there a way to view all the properties FooBar has at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this related post [Is there a tool for exploring/testing COM objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940498/is-there-a-tool-for-exploring-testing-com-objects)

Which points you to the tool [OLEView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d0kh9f4c.aspx). This should do what you want